# create multiple csv files out of one csv dataframe with different parameters in the columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Suppose I have a csv containing columns with parametric information written as a string, something like "Title, temperature=25, voltage=0.8V, x=0" for each column. the rows are statistical data, lets say 10 samples for each set of title, temperature, voltage and x.
x is some variable (0 to 10 for example) that I want to use as my x axis of the new tables
I want to find a fay to group all columns with the same title, temperature and voltage into separate tables.
each column of the new table is an iteration of the statistical data, each row is the x values.

my input csv is:

[image: input csv]

my output should be 2 csv's (because there are 2 different sets of title, temperature and voltage)

csv out 1
[image]

csv out 2
[image]

In general there can be more sets so there is no limit on how many outputs I will get.

I was thinking of doing some kind of a loop that goes through all the columns, writes down all the different combinations (excluding the x value) into a set. so in our example it will be

```
test_set = set()
#first loop to create all the table names
for i in range(csv_in.shape[1]):
    col_name = csv_in.columns[s]
    #here i need some string manipulation to extract only the title, temp and voltage from the column name
    test_set.add(col_name)
```

then another loop goes over that set and create a sub-table , then pivot it so that the x value is now the rows of the table, and saves the file with the appropriate name using the title, temp and voltage parameters.

practically I don't really know where to start since I'm pretty new to python so I would like some suggestions and any pointers you can give me would be great :)

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). For us to help you, provide a  **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: You can get the title with:
`split_title = title.split(',')[0:-1]`
`new_title = ','.join(split_title)`
Basically splitting the string on every comma, then taking from the 0th index to the last but one index and re-joining the string with commas.

Comment: You can get pretty far with split, join, replace for string manipulation. But if you get to more complex scenarios look into regex